# Вызов метода дочернего объекта из метода родительского объекта через this

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, this

```js
(function(window, document, $, undefined){

    var InvokeWindow = function() {
        this.calcSize = function() {
            this.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            this.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
            return this;
        };
        this.setElementXY = function(element, split, size) {
            $(element).css({
                'left': ''+(this.width / split[0] - size[0])+'px',
                'top': ''+(this.height / split[1] - size[1])+'px'
            });
            return this;
        };
    };

    var impl = {};

    impl.register = function() {
        this.invokeWindow = new InvokeWindow()
        .calcSize()
        .setElementXY('.dimension', [4, 2], [150, 150]);
        return this;
    };

    // повторный вызов после изменения размеров окна
    impl.rewrite = function() {
        this.invokeWindow
        .calcSize()
        .setElementXY('.dimension', [4, 2], [150, 150]);
        return this;
    };

    window.impl = impl;

})(window, document, jQuery);

$(function() {

    impl.register();

    var frameWait;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(frameWait);
        frameWait = setTimeout(impl.rewrite, 400);
    });

});
```

Этот способ работает:

```js
    impl.rewrite = function() {
        impl.invokeWindow
        .calcSize()
        .setElementXY('.dimension', [4, 2], [150, 150]);
        return this;
    };
```

А этот выдает ошибку **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calcSize' of undefined"**:

```js
    impl.rewrite = function() {
        this.invokeWindow
        .calcSize()
        .setElementXY('.dimension', [4, 2], [150, 150]);
        return this;
    };
```

В чем причина? как я могу сделать это через **this**?

Comment: очередной вопрос по потерю контекста

Comment: setTimeout убивает контекст функции, которую вы передаете

Comment: `frameWait = setTimeout(impl.rewrite.bind(impl), 400);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал ThisMan Проблема заключалась в потере контекста и решается с помощью **bind()**:

```js
frameWait = setTimeout(impl.rewrite.bind(impl), 400);
```